# Where do WCF Client cookies persist?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I am writing a wrapper around a SOAP API. I have a service reference set up in VS2010 to point to the WSDL. When I make a call to login, the API returns a session variable in a cookie.

I've set **allowCookies="true"** on my binding in config.

I've implemented two API calls in my wrapper so far: **login** and **logout**.

I have a test harness that is a simple ASP.NET application that has a page for **login** and a page for **logout**.

When **login** is submitted:

```
using (var ApiClient = new ApiClient())
            {
                ApiClient.Login(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text, txtOrganization.Text, txtIPAddress.Text);
            }
```

And now in my ApiClient.Login method:

```
using (var soapService = new WSDLInterfaceClient())
            {
                var loginCredentials = new loginRequest
                {
                    username = username,
                    password = password,
                    organization = organization
                };

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ipAddress))
                    loginCredentials.ipAddress = ipAddress;

                var loginResponse = soapService.Login(loginCredentials);
            }
```

So this all goes off without a hitch. I was thinking I would need to remove the usings and have a class level WSDLInterfaceClient that I would use within my wrapper because I figured the cookies would be wiped out each time I constructed a new client. But that is simply not the case.

The **logout** method is implemented similarly. The **logout** API call will throw an exception if you try to **logout** without being logged in. Oddly enough, when I go to my **logout** page and submit (which in turn is constructing a new wrapper client and therefore a new service client) it recognizes that I am logged in. If I try to **logout** again it throws the exception as expected.

The cookies seem to be working in that even when constructing both a new interface client and a new wrapper client on each page, the cookies persist.

While this isn't a bad thing, I am perplexed as to how it is working. Is there somewhere that ASP.NET/WCF is saving these cookies for the session? How would this work in a console app?

Comment: Do you have a WCF session enabled or required contract ? Do you use `aspnetCompatibilityMode` ?

Comment: As far as I know, I do not. I have a bare bones web.config in place. The only thing in there is the auto generated serviceModel sections with **allowCookies** changed to _true_.

Comment: It looks like WCF sessions are enabled by default: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx

Comment: By the way, are you in .NET 4.5 ? because in WCF 4.5, the inner `ChannelFactory<T>` of the `ClientBase<T>` get cached so every time you create a new instance of the client you get the cached factory.
Since the internal WCF CookieContainer is held by the channel factory, you get to reuse the same CookieContainer on every request. 
See http://kennyw.com/work/indigo/211, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh314046.aspx.

Comment: I'm using .NET 4.0. I found that if I call `                  soapService.ChannelFactory.Close();` after my login call then it will not cache the cookie. I think I would much rather manage the cookie myself than have all this magic going on under the hood. Is there anyway to set header information manually?

Comment: Maybe .NET 4.0 also cache the CookieContainer (don't know how). If you want to control yourself the cookies, you need to set `allowCookies=false` and use `OperationContextScope`. See http://megakemp.wordpress.com/2009/02/06/managing-shared-cookies-in-wcf/ Section "Ad-hoc cookie management".